# Honda City 2002 doesn't start or sputters and dies

Tags: honda, starting, city

I have a Honda City 2002, manual transmission, and it developed a problem recently. As I was driving, I turned the indicator on to signal at a turn and the electronics on the guage cluster (clock, horn, guage warning lights) went off with a slight "click" noise, like when sometimes a circuit "trips". After this, the car started sputtering and shut off on its own after a few meters.

Since then, it refuses to start with the ignition. When I turn the ignition key, "click-click" noise is heard once or twice but nothing happens. After trying a few times, absolutely no response is received, not even the clicks.

I tried jump starting the car which worked. It ran for about a kilometer but then the same issue happened. Sputtered and shut off.

What could be the problem? What should I get checked in this case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This sounds like the alternator has stopped working, so the vehicle electronics have been running off the battery until the battery went flat and everything died.

Jump starting the car will have put a small amount of charge back in the battery which will have given you some power to run the engine for the kilometer you experienced.

You need to get the charging system checked.  It could be a faulty alternator, or even bad wiring to the alternator.

Allowing the battery to become totally discharged could also have damaged the battery, reducing its capacity, so once the charging system is fixed, it may be wise to replace the battery to ensure it holds a good charge.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Alternator had burnt out due to bad wiring, and replacing both resolved the issue.